# is there a performance penalty for having several thousand dynamic columns?

Tags: mariadb

I am looking to install MariaDB and need about 2000 dynamic columns in one table. I don't need indexes. I just need to query against a dynamic column. Will this slow down query performance if I access the thousandth field? How does compare against querying against regular columns?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is an "index" inside the blob containing the Dynamic Columns.  So, the thousandth will be fast.  The number of rows will be probably be the performance issue -- unless you can find the one row you want by some other means.

Answer (score 2):

I conducted my own tests on dynamic columns. The bottom line is the more fields the more performance degrades. The bigger the size of the blob the more performance degrades. I tested with 100 fields but with huge data. It was very noticeable slowness even when doing a basic `select count(*) from thetable` the speed was very slow on 100,000 rows. I also projected the length of one dynamic column field and it took about 17 seconds over 1000 rows. When I did the same thing against a regular column it was also instant. So, dynamic columns are a nice feature but you will pay the price in performance especially if the blob is big.